# async parallel callback is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

I am getting the error "callback is not defined" when trying to use async.parallel and but I am out of leads as to why. All the examples of async.parallel have the functions inline (like the async doco https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) but as the functions I want to run have some logic in them I have tried to split them out so they are not inline. This might be my problem but I think it should be possible, I just cannot figure out from the examples how the call backs should work in this situation.

Then intention here is to have two functions go get lists of IDs from different locations then put them together and do some things on the resulting array. I have trimmed the "go do other things" as it seems irrelevant at this stage.

```
var structuresIDArray = [];

function getPublicStructures(callback){
    request({
        url: 'https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/universe/structures/?datasource=tranquility',
        method: 'GET'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(!error && !body.error && response.statusCode === 200){
            console.log('getting public locations');
            structuresIDArray.concat(JSON.parse(body));
            callback(null, structuresIDArray);
        }else{
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}

function getAssetLocationList(callback){
    db.any('select distinct "location_id" from "public"."charassets" where "location_id" is not null')
    .then(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            structuresIDArray.push(data[i].location_id);
            if(i+1===data.length){
                callback(null, structuresIDArray);
            }
        }

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        callback(err);
    });
}



function main(){

    async.parallel([ getAssetLocationList(callback), getPublicStructures(callback) ],
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            // Go do some other stuff now ...
        });
}
```

Comment: you're calling `getAssetLocationList(callback), getPublicStructures(callback)` in function main ... what is `callback` - doesn't look like you've defined it anywhere - I think you meant `async.parallel([ getAssetLocationList, getPublicStructures ] ...` - but I'm not at all familiar with `async.js`

Comment: That seems to do it thanks. I was hung up on passing in the callback and the various ways to do that but removing it entirely works. I am not really certain why this works but I will head back to google and work on my understanding of callbacks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable "callback" is not in scope when you invoke it. Try adding it to the argument list of those functions.

Like:

```
function (error, response, body, callback)
...
function (data, callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide array of functions to execute in parallel to `async.parallel`
so you need to do as follows

```
    async.parallel([getAssetLocationList,getPublicStructures],function(err, results) {
       //This callback executes when both the above functions have called their respective callbacks.
       //results[0] will contain data from getAssetLocationList
       //results[1] will contain data from getPublicStructures
    });
```

Essentially all i am changing is `getAssetLocationList(callback)` to just `getAssetLocationList` and `getPublicStructures(callback)` to `getPublicStructures` in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the reason why it doesn't work is because doing this:

```
async.parallel([ 
  getAssetLocationList(callback),
  getPublicStructures(callback)
],
function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

you are invoking `getAssetLocationList(callback)` and `getPublicStructures(callback)` passing them a variable, `callback`, that doesn't exist, hence the error *callback is not defined*.

You should instead do something like this:

```
async.parallel([
 function(callback) {
   getAssetLocationList(callback);
 },
 function(callback) {
   getPublicStructures(callback);
 }
],
function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

In this case it works because you are calling the getter functions with the parameter `callback` that you have just defined in the inline function definition `function(callback) {...}`